# How do I use a scrollbar with a listbox in a grid geometry with Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

In the following code I was just trying out all sorts of different widgets in a form. How do I get the scrollbar to show up with the listbox? All examples I've seen show a pack geometry with just the listbox and scrollbar.

```
import tkinter as tk

def Addn(): #command function for button 
    a = int(Entrya.get())
    b = int(Entryb.get())
    c = a+b
    Entrys.configure(state='normal')
    sumv.set("")
    Entrys.insert(2,c) 
    Entrys.configure(state='readonly')    
form = tk.Tk()
form.title("Comprehensive Standard Form")
form.geometry('750x500')
sumv=tk.StringVar()
btnAddn = tk.Button(form, text="Add",command=Addn)
Labela = tk.Label(form, text="A:")
Labelb = tk.Label(form, text="B:")
Labels = tk.Label(form, text="Sum:")
Entrya = tk.Entry(form)
Entryb = tk.Entry(form)
Entrys = tk.Entry(form,width=30,textvariable=sumv)
Entrys.configure(state='readonly')
#scrollbar
scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(form)
mylist = tk.Listbox(form, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert("end", "This is line number " + str(line))
mylist.grid(row=7,column=1,rowspan=3)
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )
#Placement in form
Labela.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=25, pady=25)
Entrya.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=25, pady=25)
Labelb.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=25, pady=25)
Entryb.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=25, pady=25)
Labels.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=25, pady=25)
Entrys.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=25, pady=25)
form.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're nearly there.  It needs to be gridded. `scrollbar.grid(row = 7, column = 2, rowspan = 3, sticky = tk.N+tk.S )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the scrollbar to the form using `.grid`, the same way you used `.grid` on the listbox.
Using the `sticky` parameter in `.grid` can help you align your listbox with your scrollbar.

```
mylist.grid(row=7,column=1,rowspan=3, sticky='e')
scrollbar.grid(row=7, column=2, rowspan=3, sticky='nsw')
```

`sticky` takes the arguments North, South, East, and West, abbreviated as a string containing their first letters. `sticky` tells the widget to 'stick' to the specified edges of the cell it is placed in. If it has sticky set to opposite sides of the cell, it will stretch (North and South, or East and West), otherwise it will be positioned to the side selected. scrollbar has sticky set to North and South to make sure it takes up the full height of its cell. It also has sticky set to West so that it's positioned on the left side of the cell. mylist has sticky set to East so that it is positioned on the right. With mylist on the right and scrollbar on the left, the two widgets are adjacent and appear to be one cohesive widget.